# PHP is not working on apserve

Tags: php, apache, phpmyadmin

I was working on development environment containing PHP5 and Codeigniter using Apserve pack. I wanted to upgrade to PHP 5.3 so I downloaded the ZIP file and unpack it in `c:\apserve\php5` directory. after this things got really crazy and messy.

PHP didn't worked at all, even though apache is working. the only page is working is `http://localhost/`, while phpmyadmin `http://localhost/phpmyadmin` and `http://localhost/ci` folder don't load at all. This link is shown in linkbar in my browser when I'm trying to get to phpmyadmin locally.

so how can I reconfigure php to get it working??

notes:

- php.ini located in windows folder and `c:\apserve\php6` folder.
- php folder has two location; `c:\programfiles\php6` and `c:\apserve\php6`.

I want to use c:\apserve content only.

this is my error log after removing previous errors and clean start up.

```
[Sun Apr 10 17:48:06 2011] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
PHP Warning:  Directive 'register_globals' is no longer supported in PHP 6 and greater in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Directive 'register_long_arrays' is no longer supported in PHP 6 and greater in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Directive 'magic_quotes_gpc' is no longer supported in PHP 6 and greater in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/AppServ\\php5\\ext\\php_curl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/AppServ\\php5\\ext\\php_exif.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/AppServ\\php5\\ext\\php_gd2.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/AppServ\\php5\\ext\\php_mbstring.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/AppServ\\php5\\ext\\php_mysql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/AppServ\\php5\\ext\\php_mysqli.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/AppServ\\php5\\ext\\php_openssl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/AppServ\\php5\\ext\\php_pdo.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/AppServ\\php5\\ext\\php_pdo_sqlite.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/AppServ\\php5\\ext\\php_sockets.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/AppServ\\php5\\ext\\php_sqlite.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
[Sun Apr 10 17:48:07 2011] [notice] Apache/2.2.8 (Win32) mod_ssl/2.2.8 OpenSSL/0.9.8g PHP/6.0.0-dev configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Apr 10 17:48:07 2011] [notice] Server built: Jan 18 2008 00:37:19
[Sun Apr 10 17:48:07 2011] [notice] Parent: Created child process 4872
[Sun Apr 10 17:48:07 2011] [warn] Init: Session Cache is not configured [hint: SSLSessionCache]
PHP Warning:  Directive 'register_globals' is no longer supported in PHP 6 and greater in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Directive 'register_long_arrays' is no longer supported in PHP 6 and greater in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Directive 'magic_quotes_gpc' is no longer supported in PHP 6 and greater in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/AppServ\\php5\\ext\\php_curl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/AppServ\\php5\\ext\\php_exif.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/AppServ\\php5\\ext\\php_gd2.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/AppServ\\php5\\ext\\php_mbstring.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/AppServ\\php5\\ext\\php_mysql.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/AppServ\\php5\\ext\\php_mysqli.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/AppServ\\php5\\ext\\php_openssl.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/AppServ\\php5\\ext\\php_pdo.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/AppServ\\php5\\ext\\php_pdo_sqlite.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/AppServ\\php5\\ext\\php_sockets.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'C:/AppServ\\php5\\ext\\php_sqlite.dll' - The specified module could not be found.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
[Sun Apr 10 17:48:07 2011] [notice] Child 4872: Child process is running
[Sun Apr 10 17:48:07 2011] [notice] Child 4872: Acquired the start mutex.
[Sun Apr 10 17:48:07 2011] [notice] Child 4872: Starting 64 worker threads.
[Sun Apr 10 17:48:07 2011] [notice] Child 4872: Starting thread to listen on port 80.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is contradicting information in that log output, it seems to me you are loading php5 extensions in php6.

Have you tried removing all installations of php and installing only the one you need.

If you really must have multiple versions of php running, have you considered virtualising your dev environments?

Comment: yes, you're correct, I tried after installing 5.3 and didn't work to try php6. I think now the problem is solved using removing other PHP installation in programfiles folder and relocating php.ini to windows folder

Answer (score 1):

Be sure you have enabled all extensions (MySQL in particular) in `php.ini`.

If you have backup of your previous PHP installation (folder), I'd recommend to copy & overwrite `php.ini` file.

Also check the Apache `error_log` files (in your apache folder) and see errors there, as apache would log any PHP error during start up.

Comment: before, php.ini was installed in windows folder, but not now. maybe the problem is within the location of php.ini file? how can I change the default link to that file ?